# Dropdown populated from json data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, dropdown

I want my drop down to display 2017 and 2018 from my data.
2017 and 2018 repeats a lot throughout my json data file. But I want all the 2017 data to appear when selected and all the 2018 data to be displayed when selected. Currently it shows all data and the drop down is over populated.

This is the Html code for the drop down:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-4s">
        <p>Financial Year:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4s">
            <select>
                <option *ngFor="let volumes of volumes">{{ volumes.month | 
                 date: 'yyyy' }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Angular4 code:
    export class VehicleVolumeEditComponent implements OnInit {

```
volumes: Volumes[];
groupedVolumes : any;

constructor(private volumeService: VolumeService, private router: Router) { 
    this.volumeService.getVolumes().subscribe(volumes => {
        this.volumes = volumes;
        this.groupedVolumes = this.group(this.volumes);
        this.dataOk = true;
    }
}
```

json file:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "month": "2017-03-01"
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "month": "2017-04-01"
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "month": "2017-05-01"
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "month": "2017-06-01"
}
{
    "id": 5,
    "month": "2017-07-01"
}
{
    "id": 6,
    "month": "2017-08-01"
}
{
    "id": 7,
    "month": "2017-09-01"
}
{
    "id": 8,
    "month": "2017-10-01"
}
{
    "id": 9,
    "month": "2017-11-01"
}
{
    "id": 10,
    "month": "2017-12-01"
}
{
    "id": 11,
    "month": "2018-01-01"
}
{
    "id": 12,
    "month": "2018-02-01"
}
{
    "id": 13,
    "month": "2018-03-01"
}
]
```

Comment: you should maintain array of unique years in one variable in component.ts file and use that

Comment: Problem is when it will be hooked up to the database those years will change all the time. So it needs to be populated from the json data

Comment: please post your component.ts code and volume's structure

Comment: I've added my component.ts code and my volumes file

Answer (score 0):

I would filter out the unique values in the array doing something like this -

`this.unique_volumes = this.volumes.slice().map(value => value.month = new Date(value.month).getFullYear()).filter((years, index, array) => array.indexOf(years) === index);`

And then in HTML, I would loop over the `unique_volumes` instead of `volumes`.

`<option *ngFor="let volumes of unique_volumes">{{ volumes }}</option>`

Comment: Theres a problem with this. value.month displays an error: number can't be assigned to date.

Comment: @L.C update also the HTML code with the above provided. you have to change the volumes.month with date pipe, just to {{ volumes }}.

Comment: The problem with this is the slice() function. This requires a number.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
.
.
volumes: Volumes[];
years: [] = [];
groupedVolumes : any;

constructor(private volumeService: VolumeService, private router: Router, private datePipe: DatePipe) { 

}


ngOnInit(){
    this.volumeService.getVolumes().subscribe(volumes => {
        this.volumes = volumes;
        for(let volume of volumes){
          if(this.years.indexOf(datePipe.formatDate(volume.month, 'yyyy')) === -1)
           this.years.push(datePipe.formatDate(volume.month, 'yyyy'));
        }
        this.groupedVolumes = this.group(this.volumes);
        this.dataOk = true;
    }

}
```

use this in html:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4s">
    <p>Financial Year:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4s">
        <select>
            <option *ngFor="let year of years">{{ year }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be right but I'm struggling to get it to work. There seems to be a problem with the DatePipe. It only has a transform function rather than formatDate. Also it doesn't like years: [ ] = [ ]